# How to upload files using pure SCP not SFTP in node?

Tags: node.js, electron, scp

I need to upload some files from a NodeJS / Electron application to an embedded system that only supports SCP but not SFTP.
I tested the libraries [**scp2**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scp2) and [**node-scp**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-scp). They manage to connect to the embedded system but then immediatly fail with exit code 127. This indicates that the server doesn't support SFTP. Actually, I wasn't expecting this because the SCP protocol should be used. It seems like these librarys are using SFTP, contrary to their own names.

I can reproduce the same error message when I use WinSCP in STFP mode instead of SCP.

Is there any node library that supports pure SCP? Or am I forced to fall back to the command-line `scp` to copy?

Comment: Well, at least the documentation for `scp2` clearly state that it "implements `scp` **in a[n] `sftp` way**" (emphasis mine), so that library doesn't look like it would support plain SCP...

Comment: And checking the [node-scp code](https://github.com/maitrungduc1410/node-scp-async), it clearly uses SFTP only too. I has nothing to do with SCP either.

Answer (score 0):

I tried node-ssh and node-scp but internally they use SFTP like you said.

https://github.com/pghalliday/scp1

above one seems to use SCP.